# asp Custom Validator fires too late

Tags: c#, asp.net, customvalidator

I have a form with a custom validator for the date:

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cusCustom"
 ControlToValidate="fdate"
 Display="None"
 OnServerValidate="customdate"
 ErrorMessage="You need to book 24 hours earlier" />
<ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender 
ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender4"
TargetControlId="cusCustom" runat="server">
</ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
```

And the function behind:

```
    protected void customdate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
    {
        string dateString = String.Format("{0} {1}:{2}:00", fdate.Text, TimeSelector1.Hour, TimeSelector1.Minute);
        DateTime selectedDateTime = new DateTime();
        if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out selectedDateTime))
        {
            if (selectedDateTime > DateTime.Now.AddHours(24))
            {
                e.IsValid = true;
            } else {
                 e.IsValid = false;
            }
        }
     }
```

The problem is that it works fine, it detects what it needs to detect and it triggers the warning, but... it triggers it too late! If I enter a wrong date in the form, I am able to submit it, and I will find the warning about this bad validation next time I open the modalpopup with the form to enter a new booking.

All the other validators I have in the same form work fine. This is the button that launches the form:

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnNew" runat="server" Text="New" CausesValidation="false" />
```

It has the `CausesValidation` set to false, and that works very well for the normal validators. Is only the custom one that runs too late...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably have your popup firing an event to check whether the input is valid after you close it. I'll provide you with some pseudo-code.

```
<popupModalBox OnClose="PopupModal_OnClose" />
```

Triggering a method on the server

```
void PopupModal_OnClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        // Do something
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```